# XML parsing in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, parsing

I need to parse some simple XML strings, but can figure out what I am doing wrong.
The code returns an empty recordset.
I need to list the values in

### Ms sql Code:

```sql
DECLARE @XML XML
    = N'<ArrayOfPrintLine xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/KTKservice" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <PrintLine>
      <PType>SmallCenter</PType>
      <Value>XXX STORE NAME</Value>
   </PrintLine>
   <PrintLine>
      <PType>SmallCenter</PType>
      <Value>XXX STORE ADRESS</Value>
   </PrintLine>
   <PrintLine>
      <PType>SmallCenter</PType>
      <Value>XXX XXX XXX MVA</Value>
   </PrintLine>
</ArrayOfPrintLine>';

SELECT tbl.PrintLine.value('PType[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS _Type,
       tbl.PrintLine.value('Value[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS _ValueStr
FROM @XML.nodes('/ArrayOfPrintLine/PrintLine') AS tbl(PrintLine);
```

This is the way i want to display the XML

| _Type | _ValueStr |
| --- | --- |
| SmallCenter | XXX STORE |
| SmallCenter | XXX STORE ADRESS |
| SmallCenter | XXX XXX XXX MVA |

Comment: You don't define your (default) namespace in your SQL getting the data. As soon as you do, it works fine.

Comment: Thanks Thom A. That was it.
Added
with XMLNAMESPACES (default 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/KTKservice')